# Drop-down menu working sporadically

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a some drop-down menus set up here: http://emgraphics.net/sokoleye_wp  The problem is they only work sporadically - three out of four times I can't click on a link and the menu disappears.  However, there isn't any pattern - no page where it works regularly (or doesn't), no particular menu/link that does or doesn't work, sometimes it works on the first try, sometimes not at all until I switch pages.  The problem seems consistent across browser/platform (I tried a bunch of options in Browserstack). Even IE follows the pattern!  These are just a standard menu set up in WordPress.  I assume there must be some css somewhere that is interfering, or something with the random images in the header? But why wouldn't it just stay broken/non-functional (or not)? Any idea what I am missing here?  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a border top to the above example if you still want to have the visual effect of a gap. Replace your existing CSS for the element below and it should fix your problem.

```
#access ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    z-index: 99999;
    border-top:4px solid #7C7461;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me (Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m) there is a gap between the menu items and the drop-down list. When the cursor hits this gap it is not in a hover state over the button or the list, causing the list to disappear.

Try changing the CSS for **#access ul ul** to:

```
#access ul ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 0;
float: left;
width: 180px;
z-index: 99999;
padding-top: 4px;
}
```

..that should fix the issue.

Comment: Not a problem. I would suggest using padding rather than a border (as Vector suggested), then if you ever change the background color you will not have to update the #access ul ul color too.